# Break divs by using :nth-child properly

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to stack divs next to each other and break the divs after three child elements.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap a {
   float:left;
}

.wrap a:nth-child(4n) {
   clear:left;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6setwth/2/). The first line displays fine, with 3 child divs next to each other. *But* the second line has 4 divs when it should have 3. How can I make it so only 3 divs are stacked next to each other using `:nth-child` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-child(3n+1)`:

```css
.wrap a {
   float:left;
}

.wrap a:nth-child(3n+1) {
   clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
</div>
```

Comment: need every 4 element clear and using 3n+1 you will get 4,7,10 element clear property apply

Answer (score 1):

Explain:  Using a formula `(an + b)`. Description: `a represents` a cycle size, `n` is a counter `(starts at 0)`, and `b` is an offset value.

```css
.wrap a {
   float:left;
}

.wrap a:nth-child(3n+1) {
   clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
  <a> hello </a>
</div>
```