# Add br tag after few anchor tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML:

```
<td class="sorting_1">
   <a href="/show/1">1</a>
   <a href="/show/2">2</a>
   <a href="/show/3">3</a>
   <a href="/show/4">4</a>
   <a href="/show/5">5</a>
   <a href="/show/6">6</a>
</td>
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I want to have such that the `<br>` tag is added after 3 anchor tag, so the output looks like following:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

How to do in jQuery?

Comment: Same question, solution using CSS only: [break after nth child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513275/break-divs-by-using-nth-child-properly)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if is `<a>` is multiple of 3 so add `<br>` like:

```js
$('table tr td a').each((index,el) => {  
   var indexPlus = index + 1;
   if(indexPlus % 3 === 0){
    $(el).after('<br>');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/show/1">1</a>
      <a href="/show/2">2</a>
      <a href="/show/3">3</a>
      <a href="/show/4">4</a>
      <a href="/show/5">5</a>
      <a href="/show/6">6</a>
      <a href="/show/7">7</a>
      <a href="/show/8">8</a>
      <a href="/show/9">9</a>
      <a href="/show/10">10</a>
      <a href="/show/11">11</a>
      <a href="/show/12">12</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/show/1">1</a>
      <a href="/show/2">2</a>
      <a href="/show/3">3</a>
      <a href="/show/4">4</a>
      <a href="/show/5">5</a>
      <a href="/show/6">6</a>
      <a href="/show/7">7</a>
      <a href="/show/8">8</a>
      <a href="/show/9">9</a>
      <a href="/show/10">10</a>
      <a href="/show/11">11</a>
      <a href="/show/12">12</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Reference:

- [.after()](https://api.jquery.com/after/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use css selector `nth-child(3n)` for select each 3 child
and method `.after` to append html to this third child

```js
$('.sorting_1 a:nth-child(3n)').after('<br/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td class="sorting_1">
    <a href="/show/1">1</a>
    <a href="/show/2">2</a>
    <a href="/show/3">3</a>
    <a href="/show/4">4</a>
    <a href="/show/5">5</a>
    <a href="/show/6">6</a>
    <a href="/show/1">1</a>
    <a href="/show/2">2</a>
    <a href="/show/3">3</a>
    <a href="/show/4">4</a>
    <a href="/show/5">5</a>
    <a href="/show/6">6</a>
  </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose that u have a table element, this is how it should looks like with jQuery

```
$('table tr td a:nth-child(3n+3)').each(function(){
    $(this).after('<br>');
});
```

and this is how u do it without jQuery

```
let a_tags = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td a:nth-child(3n+3)');

a_tags.forEach(element => {
    let br = document.createElement('br');
        element.after(br);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While you [can't add HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22511546/2181514) using CSS pseudo elements, you can still achieve the same layout by adding an empty string and using `display:block`

```
a:nth-child(3n)::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
}
```

As this uses css, assuming you load your css in the `<head>`, you won't get a FOUC (flash of unstyled content) while waiting for your js to be parsed and run.

There's also an existing answer using css `display:float`: [break after nth child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513275/break-divs-by-using-nth-child-properly)

```css
a:nth-child(3n)::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/show/1">1</a>
      <a href="/show/2">2</a>
      <a href="/show/3">3</a>
      <a href="/show/4">4</a>
      <a href="/show/5">5</a>
      <a href="/show/6">6</a>
      <a href="/show/7">7</a>
      <a href="/show/8">8</a>
      <a href="/show/9">9</a>
      <a href="/show/10">10</a>
      <a href="/show/11">11</a>
      <a href="/show/12">12</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/show/1">1</a>
      <a href="/show/2">2</a>
      <a href="/show/3">3</a>
      <a href="/show/4">4</a>
      <a href="/show/5">5</a>
      <a href="/show/6">6</a>
      <a href="/show/7">7</a>
      <a href="/show/8">8</a>
      <a href="/show/9">9</a>
      <a href="/show/10">10</a>
      <a href="/show/11">11</a>
      <a href="/show/12">12</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```